# UICollectionView Horizontal Paging not centered

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have a horizontal scrolling collectionView with each cell the size of the view. When I page through the collectionView it doesn't page by cell. The cells aren't in the center of the screen. I've tried a bunch of things to try to fix it and haven't had any luck.
Here's a video of the problem: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tXsxWelk16w
Any ideas?

Comment: The width of the page is determined by the width of the collection view. How are you setting the size of your cell? Are you setting it to the size of the collection view, or its superview?

Comment: @rdelmar setting it based off of the size of the collection view

Comment: That should have worked. Make sure that you also set the minimumLineSpacing to 0 (the default is 10).

Answer (score 166, accepted):

Remove spaces between items. For horizontal scrolling collection view set minimum line spacing to 0. You can do this with interface builder or with method of `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protocol:

```
- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
                   layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout 
        minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0;    
}
```

[image]

Another way is making your cell's width less than collectionView's width for a value of horizontal space between items. Then add section insets with left and right insets that equal a half of horizontal space between items. For example, your minimum line spacing is 10:

```
- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                   layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
        minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return 10;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout 
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return CGSizeMake(collectionView.frame.size.width - 10, collectionView.frame.size.height);
}

- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
                        layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout 
        insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 5);
}
```

[image]

And third way: manipulate collectionView scroll in `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:` method:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView == self.collectionView) {
        CGPoint currentCellOffset = self.collectionView.contentOffset;
        currentCellOffset.x += self.collectionView.frame.size.width / 2;
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:currentCellOffset];
        [self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPath
                                    atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally
                                            animated:YES];
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You can't have cells with size of the collection view, horizontal spaces between them and centered pages. Make a choise.

Comment: Another way: make you cell's width = (collectionView width - minimumLineSpacing) and add a section insets with left and right insets equal minimumLineSpacing / 2.

Comment: First option is simplest and works perfectly! In case anyone wants Swift 2.* delegate function:     `func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }`

Comment: Hi, check my answer down here. Two lines from Apple. @VladimirKravchenko

Comment: Excellent!! The second option did the trick for me :) Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 43):

Demo here in **Swift 3**:
https://github.com/damienromito/CollectionViewCustom

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {

    let pageWidth = Float(itemWidth + itemSpacing)
    let targetXContentOffset = Float(targetContentOffset.pointee.x)
    let contentWidth = Float(collectionView!.contentSize.width  )
    var newPage = Float(self.pageControl.currentPage)

    if velocity.x == 0 {
        newPage = floor( (targetXContentOffset - Float(pageWidth) / 2) / Float(pageWidth)) + 1.0
    } else {
        newPage = Float(velocity.x > 0 ? self.pageControl.currentPage + 1 : self.pageControl.currentPage - 1)
        if newPage < 0 {
            newPage = 0
        }
        if (newPage > contentWidth / pageWidth) {
            newPage = ceil(contentWidth / pageWidth) - 1.0
        }
    }
    self.pageControl.currentPage = Int(newPage)
    let point = CGPoint (x: CGFloat(newPage * pageWidth), y: targetContentOffset.pointee.y)
    targetContentOffset.pointee = point
}
```

**Swift 4**:

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {

    let pageWidth = Float(itemWidth + itemSpacing)
    let targetXContentOffset = Float(targetContentOffset.pointee.x)
    let contentWidth = Float(collectionView!.contentSize.width  )
    var newPage = Float(self.pageControl.currentPage)

    if velocity.x == 0 {
        newPage = floor( (targetXContentOffset - Float(pageWidth) / 2) / Float(pageWidth)) + 1.0
    } else {
        newPage = Float(velocity.x > 0 ? self.pageControl.currentPage + 1 : self.pageControl.currentPage - 1)
        if newPage < 0 {
            newPage = 0
        }
        if (newPage > contentWidth / pageWidth) {
            newPage = ceil(contentWidth / pageWidth) - 1.0
        }
    }

    self.pageControl.currentPage = Int(newPage)
    let point = CGPoint (x: CGFloat(newPage * pageWidth), y: targetContentOffset.pointee.y)
    targetContentOffset.pointee = point
}
```

Comment: Swift 4 code is here https://github.com/damienromito/CollectionViewCustom/blob/master/CollectionViewCustom/ViewController.swift

Comment: How do I control the speed at which it scrolls? I want to increase it.

Comment: Thank You For This!

Comment: In order to work, you have to disable "Paging Enabled" in your collection view

Answer (score 24):

Swift version of @vlad-che accepted answer:

```
extension GoodsViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {

        return 10
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        let frameSize = collectionView.frame.size
        return CGSize(width: frameSize.width - 10, height: frameSize.height)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {

        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 5, bottom: 0, right: 5)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

Swift 4 solution to remove line spacing to keep cells centered:

```
public func collectionView(
  _ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
  layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, 
  minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int
) -> CGFloat {
  return 0
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Swift 3

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if scrollView == self.collectionView {
            var currentCellOffset = self.collectionView.contentOffset
            currentCellOffset.x += self.collectionView.frame.width / 2
            if let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: currentCellOffset) {
              self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It works but you see some weird visual effect every time you move from page to page.

Comment: Works perfect for me, thank you for your answer, I was looking desperately

Answer (score 5):

Being able to have cells that are smaller the `collectionView` frame with space between the cells allows for hinting to the user that there other cells either side to scroll to which is a big win for UX. But for the centering of the pages doesn't work as expected with each cell progressively becoming more offset as the user scrolls. I've found the following to work well. The centering/snapping animation on each cell is almost invisible to user since it is only tweaking where the `collectionView` scrolling would end naturally rather than jerking the `collectionView` to quickly scroll to another `indexPath`. It's still important to to have the `sectionInset` property set large enough to allow cell not to stick to the containing frame edges. Also since there are spaces between the cells the target could land on an `indexPath` of nil which would cause the `collectionView` to scroll back to the start. I've fixed this offsetting a little and then trying again but different approaches could be taken here.

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
                 withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity
          targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset
{
    //Ensure the scrollview is the collectionview we care about
    if (scrollView == self.collectionView) {

        // Find cell closest to the frame centre with reference from the targetContentOffset.
        CGPoint frameCentre = self.collectionView.center;
        CGPoint targetOffsetToCentre = CGPointMake((* targetContentOffset).x + frameCentre.x, (* targetContentOffset).y + frameCentre.y);

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:targetOffsetToCentre];

            //Check for "edgecase" that the target will land between cells and then find a close neighbour to prevent scrolling to index {0,0}.
        while (!indexPath) {
            targetOffsetToCentre.x += ((UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout).minimumInteritemSpacing;
            indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:targetOffsetToCentre];
        }

        // Find the centre of the target cell
        CGPoint centreCellPoint = [self.collectionView layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath].center;

        // Calculate the desired scrollview offset with reference to desired target cell centre.
        CGPoint desiredOffset = CGPointMake(centreCellPoint.x - frameCentre.x, centreCellPoint.y - frameCentre.y);
        *targetContentOffset = desiredOffset;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Swift 3.0  set your own UICollectionViewFlowLayout

```
let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: 154)
layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
collectionView?.collectionViewLayout = layout
```

Comment: Replacing view controller's width `view.bounds.width` with `UIScreen.main.bounds.width` solved in my case.

Comment: I put this code in scrollViewDidEndDecelerating method and pagination started working perfect.

Answer (score 5):

If you're after the behaviour of `collectionView.isPagingEnabled` (so with 'proper inertia feeling' etc) but without wrong offsets when setting a contentInset or spacing, this is what you need:

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
    let itemWidth = cellSize.width + spacing
    let inertialTargetX = targetContentOffset.pointee.x
    let offsetFromPreviousPage = (inertialTargetX + collectionView.contentInset.left).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: itemWidth)
    
    // snap to the nearest page
    let pagedX: CGFloat
    if offsetFromPreviousPage > itemWidth / 2 {
        pagedX = inertialTargetX + (itemWidth - offsetFromPreviousPage)
    } else {
        pagedX = inertialTargetX - offsetFromPreviousPage
    }
    
    let point = CGPoint(x: pagedX, y: targetContentOffset.pointee.y)
    targetContentOffset.pointee = point
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Doesn't require you to get rid of inter item spacing

Answer (score 2):

The code I just saw from Apple Official Guides and Sample Code:

> AssetViewController.swift:

```
self.collectionView?.isPagingEnabled = true
self.collectionView?.frame = view.frame.insetBy(dx: -20.0, dy: 0.0)
```

this code enlarges the collection view so that it extends out of the screen, while the content is just within the screen edges

Comment: this code enlarges the collection view so that it extends out of the screen, while the content is just within the screen edges.

Answer (score 2):

Add Collection View To The **Full Screen**, **Remove Spacing Between Cells** and **Estimated Size Will be None**

[image]

Add This Collection View Delegate Method

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: collectionView.frame.height)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

jsut add override this delegate

`public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout  collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,  minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat { return 0 }`

Answer (score 1):

After having a similar issue, I fixed mine by realizing that when using horizontal scrolling the height is now the width and the width is now the height because the default is set for vertical scrolling. Try switching the values and see if that helps. 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/UsingtheFlowLayout/UsingtheFlowLayout.html

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3 solution** based on @Santos's answer, for use if if you have a regular horizontally paging collection view *without* a page control like Paolo was using in his Swift 3 example.

I used this to solve an issue where a horizontally paging cell full screen cells with a custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout animator didn't finish rotating AND ended up offset so that the the edges of a full screen cell frame were increasingly horizontally off set from the collection view's bounds as you scrolled (like in the video OP shared).

```
 func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {

    // Ensure the scrollview is the one on the collectionView we care are working with 
    if (scrollView == self.collectionView) {
        
        // Find cell closest to the frame centre with reference from the targetContentOffset.
        let frameCenter: CGPoint = self.collectionView.center
        var targetOffsetToCenter: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: targetContentOffset.pointee.x + frameCenter.x, y: targetContentOffset.pointee.y + frameCenter.y)
        var indexPath: IndexPath? = self.collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: targetOffsetToCenter)
        
        // Check for "edge case" where the target will land right between cells and then next neighbor to prevent scrolling to index {0,0}.
        while indexPath == nil {
            targetOffsetToCenter.x += 10
            indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: targetOffsetToCenter)
        }
        // safe unwrap to make sure we found a valid index path
        if let index = indexPath { 
            // Find the centre of the target cell
            if let centerCellPoint: CGPoint = collectionView.layoutAttributesForItem(at: index)?.center {
                
                // Calculate the desired scrollview offset with reference to desired target cell centre.
                let desiredOffset: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: centerCellPoint.x - frameCenter.x, y: centerCellPoint.y - frameCenter.y)
                targetContentOffset.pointee = desiredOffset
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that [isPagingEnabled](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619432-ispagingenabled) doesn't consider the contentSize, but rather the collection bounds:

> the scroll view stops on multiples of the scroll view’s bounds when the user scrolls.

To achieve what we want, we need to calculate the next offset ourselves and turn off isPagingEnabled.

[image]

As you can see in the image above, the second cell should start at:

`One side + Cell - Next cell visible part`.

Here's a delegate that calculates just that:
https://gist.github.com/danielCarlosCE/7a5f80dc6087773ba147be4dc72da826

Answer (score 0):

One more implementation with the Compositional Layout.

```swift
@IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // collectionView.dataSource = self
    // collectionView.register(YourCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "YourCellReuseIdentifier")
    // collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = false
    
    let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
        widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
        heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0))
    let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
        
    let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
        widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
        heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0))
    let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])
        
    let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
    section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .groupPagingCentered
        
    let config = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayoutConfiguration()
    let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section, configuration: config)
        
    collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(layout, animated: false)
}
```

[Implementing Modern Collection Views](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/collection_views/implementing_modern_collection_views)

[UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewcompositionallayout)

Answer (score 0):

if you need cell full of the device screen width. you can use 'UIScreen.main.bounds.width' to get width cell

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageCollectionView: UICollectionView!

func collectionSetup() {
    let imageFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let imageSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    imageFlowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    imageFlowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    imageFlowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: imageSize, height: imageSize * 2)
    imageFlowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    imageFlowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    imageFlowLayout.estimatedItemSize = .zero
    imageCollectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(imageFlowLayout, animated: true)
    imageCollectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
}
```