# Swift - How to fetch a UICollectionViewCell from UICollectionView based on index position in integer

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting a index of data as int. I m getting position of my data which can be 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 .. so on. How can i use these int to fetch colletionviewcell from collectionview.

on each scrolling i m getting index of cell as int for e.g initally it will be 0 for next swipe the number will be 1, next swipe nos will be 2 and so on.

```
    func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
            let layout = self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
            let cellWidthIncludingSpacing = layout.itemSize.width + layout.minimumLineSpacing
            var offset = targetContentOffset.pointee
            let index = (offset.x + scrollView.contentInset.left) / cellWidthIncludingSpacing
            let roundIndex = round(index)
            offset = CGPoint(x: roundIndex * cellWidthIncludingSpacing - scrollView.contentInset.left, y: -scrollView.contentInset.top)
            targetContentOffset.pointee = offset

for cell in collectionView.visibleCells as! [CaurosalCollectionViewCell] {
            // do something

            print(cell.title.text)
        }
    }
```

[expected output](https://www.google.co.in/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2FgD0D2.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F45383395%2Fhow-to-create-horizontal-carousel-in-ios-10-swift-3&docid=422us3p6Sf5_WM&tbnid=EYNmVgStdOwGlM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwi7_euQ3ejWAhVKsI8KHfu5C6IQMwgmKAEwAQ..i&w=1280&h=720&bih=703&biw=1280&q=ios%20cards%20carousel&ved=0ahUKEwi7_euQ3ejWAhVKsI8KHfu5C6IQMwgmKAEwAQ&iact=mrc&uact=8)

Comment: where do you want to fetch the cell? on scroll?

Comment: yes on scrollViewWillEndDragging

Comment: You can not retrieve the cell because it is not yet on screen. Can you be more specific about what are you trying to do ?

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 1):

You can use yourCollectionView?.indexPathsForVisibleItems but it returns an array.
So you have to compute which indexPath is visible at the current contentOffset.

Something like:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let visibleRect = CGRect(origin: yourCollectionView.contentOffset, size: yourCollectionView.bounds.size)
    let visiblePoint = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(visibleRect.midX), y: CGFloat(visibleRect.midY))
    let visibleIndexPath: IndexPath? = yourCollectionView.indexPathForItem(at: visiblePoint)
}
```

**Edit**

You need to look into UICollectionViewLayout and specifically layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath). You can update the layout based on the current IndexPath without going through the scrollview delegate.

If you wish to use the scollview delegate I believe this question was better answered here: [How to create a centered UICollectionView like in Spotify's Player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35045155/how-to-create-a-centered-uicollectionview-like-in-spotifys-player)

Comment: i have updated my func in question i need to fetch cell based on roundIndex . I am getting "Cannot convert value of type 'CGFloat' to expected argument type 'CGPoint'" i dont have CGPoint i am adjusting the horizontal collectionview cell in the center and i need to increase its z-positions

Comment: can u check my code how can i fetch cell based on roundIndex variable

Answer (score 1):

You can create indexpath from this index, providing the section (I am taking it 0). If no section then it is zero. Further, passing this indexpath to fetch the cell,
now you have to typecast the cell into required type then you can use it

```
 let indexpath = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)
 guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexpath) as? CaurosalCollectionViewCell else { return }
```

Comment: i am not able to fetch my cell its always going in return statement