# Collection view cell always in the centre while scrolling

Tags: ios, layout, uicollectionview, cell

I'm trying to create a collection view similar to this one:
[image: ][1]

When I scroll, each cell should go through the centre of the view.

In other words I am looking for the solution you can see [in this GIF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35045155/how-to-create-a-centered-uicollectionview-like-in-spotifys-player). I tried each solution from this one topic but they didn't work.

Can somebody help me with a good tutorial or good advices?

Comment: That's a picker view, not a collection view.

Comment: @Kxko google about carousel effect in iOS swift.Or just search on you tube there are many similar solutions.

Comment: @JoshCaswell i know. I just want to achieve the same behavior :)

Comment: This Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36710965/1462718 works for sure. I've seen it in action myself.