# Horizontal CollectionView Spacing not working properly Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview

Hello I am making horizontal collection view image on screen then scroll to view second the problem is when i give spacing to my collectionView then scrol to another images it show half image of another record mean half image one side and image of first record guide me how i give proper spacing i want to show single image on screen the scrol to view second with spacing 
this is screen shot of spacing

[image]

this is what I am facing when i scroll 1 or 2 images then it show me half image of another record
[image]

I am already using CollectionViewLayout to give equal width and height to my cell

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
            let width = collectionView.frame.size.width
            let height = collectionView.frame.size.height
            return CGSize.init(width: width, height: height)

        }
```

Comment: Add the screenshot of the problem you are facing.

Comment: see my updated question

Answer (score 0):

To make `UICollectionView` perfectly, you need to:

1. Add collectionView's `delegate` and `data source` properties
2. You need to specify the size of the `UICollectionView` cell in `storyboard` or through code by implementing `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` methods.
3. For spacing, you need to give the `cell spacing`.
4. Provide the `section insets` in case you need it.

And you are good to go.

### Edit

Here is the code which you can use to give the size and spacing details of `UICollectionViewCell`.

Also don't forget to conform to `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protocol.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
{
    return CGSize(width: 300.0, height: 135.0)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat
{
    return 15
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets
{
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 15, bottom: 0, right: 15)
}
```

Comment: it gives space between cell but still its showing half half cells  of two reocrds i want to see one record in centered

Comment: i want view something like that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35045155/how-to-create-a-centered-uicollectionview-like-in-spotifys-player

Comment: Check if the clip to bounds of `UIImageView` in selected.

Comment: just select clip to bounds for uiimageview but still same issue :(

Comment: Check if the above `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` methods are called.

Comment: In that case you need to add some more code for me to debug the issue.

Comment: bro i want exactly this type of collection view in this link code is in objective c please guide me to make like this https://github.com/raheelsadiq/UICollectionView-horizontal-paging-with-3-items