# UICollectionView with cell partially visible

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I would like to make a collectionView that can be scrolled horizontally and has only one cell item visible and one partially visible. Cells should take the whole height of the collectionView.

I have played with the sectionInset of collectionView. But couldn't achieve my target.

**My Code:**

```
import UIKit

class BooksController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var booksCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 20)
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: booksCollectionView.frame.width, height: booksCollectionView.frame.height)
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 10
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        booksCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout


        booksCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "BookCell", bundle: .main), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "BookCell")
        booksCollectionView.dataSource = self
        booksCollectionView.delegate = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}

extension BooksController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "BookCell", for: indexPath) as? BookCell {
            return cell
        }
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }
}

extension BooksController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
//    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
//        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 20)
//    }
}
```

**Target (Something similar to the collectionView here)**

[image: Something similar to this]

**My Output**

[image: This is my output]

Comment: Seems to be what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35045155/how-to-create-a-centered-uicollectionview-like-in-spotifys-player

Comment: Reduce cell width to 50 or 100 as your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Use this piece of code

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let width = self.view.frame.width - 100
        let height = self.view.frame.height
        return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    }
```

Don't forget to add this delegate

> UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

Comment: It might be better to use the `collectionView.frame` instead of `self.view.frame` since the `collectionView` might be smaller than the `view`.

Comment: When the collectionView is scrolled, I need the second(next) items should be visible fully. I have tried the above way. But in this way, when I scroll, the second item is not visible fully. instead, the rest of it is visible

Comment: What do you mean is not visible fully? You want the snap effect? How could it be not visible fully if its width is less big than the collection view?

Answer (score -1):

**Add UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
    }
```

Comment: When the collectionView is scrolled, I need the second(next) items should be visible fully. I have tried the above way. But in this way, when I scroll, the second item is not visible fully. instead, the rest of it is visible

Answer (score -1):

Use this Pod **MSPeekCollectionViewDelegateImplementation**

[GitHub](https://github.com/MaherKSantina/MSPeekCollectionViewDelegateImplementation)

Answer (score -1):

You can use if you need to show half of the second collection view cell

collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.init(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 10)

For height and with of the collection view you can try CollectionViewLayout delegate

Comment: In storyboard, remove default insets in  UICollectionView.