# Swift - Apply effect on the UICollectionView cell cut in half

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, cell, effect

I have 5 cells in my collectionView but I only display 2.5 cells

For Example in my collectionView I have this : [][][

'[]' represents one cell in my collectionView. We can scroll horizontally to see the next cell.

What I want is to apply some effect like opacity to the last cell visible cut in half to have a smooth UI.

How can i do this ?

EDIT: A sample what i want

[image]

But when the cell cut in half is totally visible (not cut anymore) the transparent effect will disappear and the next cell cut in half will have the same effect

Thanks
Best Regard,

Comment: Can you show us or attach any link for sample effect you needed ?

Comment: Sure, i'm going to edit my post. I don't know if the picture will be helpfull

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35045155/how-to-create-a-centered-uicollectionview-like-in-spotifys-player check this

Comment: @Vicky_Vignesh Thanks for your answer. But I don't think your link is helpfull in my case. I don't want to center the cell like Spotify.

Comment: Hi @kirusamma is it fixed ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code, It works I have tested It.

```
//make this variable global
var previousIndexPath : IndexPath = IndexPath()


func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let indexPaths = fullyVisibleCells(collectionView)
    if !previousIndexPath.isEmpty {

        // Reset the Cell with transparent color
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: previousIndexPath) as! collectionViewCell
        cell.baseView.backgroundColor = .white //Here I used White color 
    }
    if !indexPaths.isEmpty {

        // Highlight the Cell with Desired color
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPaths.first!) as! collectionViewCell
        cell.baseView.backgroundColor = .red // Here I have used Red color
        previousIndexPath = indexPaths.first!

    }

}

func fullyVisibleCells(_ inCollectionView: UICollectionView) -> [IndexPath] {

    var returnCells = [IndexPath]()

    var vCells = inCollectionView.visibleCells
    vCells = vCells.filter({ cell -> Bool in
        let cellRect = inCollectionView.convert(cell.frame, to: inCollectionView.superview)
        return inCollectionView.frame.contains(cellRect)
    })

    vCells.forEach({
        if let pth = inCollectionView.indexPath(for: $0) {
            returnCells.append(pth)
        }
    })

    return returnCells

}
```

[image: First]
[image: Second]

Comment: Sorry for my late answer. Thanks but it didn't work for me but i solved this issue. I'am going to post the code. Thanks again !