# Scrollable CollectionView opacity on noncentered images?

Tags: swift

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35045155/how-to-create-a-centered-uicollectionview-like-in-spotifys-player) post i managed to solve my problem of having an image centered and zoomed in a collectionView horizontal scroll (using the answer with the "ZoomAndSnapFlowLayout" class). Now I want to make the other images have some opacity beside the one centered. i've tried setting the alpha to 1.0 in the function for the zoom but no luck. I still think it would be that kind of approach that would be the solution though.
I'm still in school so my knowledge is still quite low regarding all this.

Comment: Maybe this flow layout will help you https://github.com/ink-spot/UPCarouselFlowLayout

Comment: Thank you, I did take a look at both that and iCarousel before but i don't want to depend on outside libraries for this.