# Collectionview specific layout

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

I am trying to find an approach to get my collectionview to have this layout for the cells with paging

The image should always be in center and have parts from left and right if they existed[image]

Comment: You may check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49844718).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following library will provide the same output that you desire also it has many more features which will help you to do more attractive transition animation also.

https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Comment: But do you have any idea on how to do it native without libraries