# UICollectionView contentOffset wrong from second page

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I'm making an paging `UICollectionView` and use `KRLCollectionViewGridLayout` for custom 3x3 grid layout. Everything in first page run perfectly like image below with this settings:

```
KRLCollectionViewGridLayout *flowLayout = [[KRLCollectionViewGridLayout alloc] init];
flowLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
flowLayout.aspectRatio = 1;
flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(2, 25, 10, 15);
flowLayout.interitemSpacing = 25;
flowLayout.lineSpacing = 25;
flowLayout.numberOfItemsPerLine = 3;
```

[image]

But when I'm scrolled to second page, the problem start: The content offset of my collection being misaligned like this image, it isn't grid 3x3 anymore:

[image]

I take a night for research the solution but seem like they're not help me to solve this problem. How can I fix it now?

Comment: how are you calculating cell size?

Comment: @cyril using `KRLCollectionViewGridLayout` is auto estimate the cell size. I just need to set `flowLayout.numberOfItemsPerLine = 3;` then it will fit with my collection frame.

Comment: Maybe the unintended effects you are seeing are due to the library? Have you tried a) achieving the layout without using the library b) using the library in a separate empty project?

Comment: Yes I did, after using that lib and got error I've setting UICollectionViewFlowLayout manually and still get this problem:
`UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    flowLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
    flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10;
    flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 25;
    flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(2, 25, 10, 15);
    flowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(90, 90);`

Comment: Just realized you're trying to center collection view cells while paging. Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29658328/uicollectionview-horizontal-paging-not-centered)?

Comment: Of course, I tried but it's not work with my problem