# UICollectionView Paging view is cut off - paging not working

Tags: ios, pagination, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, horizontal-scrolling

I am implementing a UICollectionView that needs to page horizontally.  The UICollectionViewCell needs to be the same size as the UICollectionView.  The cell has 2 embedded rows.  The first has a UITextView and a UIButton and the second has a UITextView.

The UICollectionviewCell and the constraints work in preview for different sizes of the iPhone (e.g. 4s, 8, 8plus) but when running in the simulator paging doesn't work correctly and the cell's width, I guess, isn't centered and the cell doesn't move far enough to reach the next cell making the cell look cutoff.

I have tried the solution at this url: [UICollectionView Horizontal Paging not centered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29658328/uicollectionview-horizontal-paging-not-centered)

but I can't seem to get the width and centering correct.  The code I'm using is below.

```
internal class AccessViewController : UIViewController,    UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

//...

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! PagerContentCollectionViewCell

    //Set the cell title
    cell.txtTitle.text = "title"

    //add a target for the call capability
    cell.btnCall.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didButtonClick), for: .touchUpInside)

    //description
    cell.txtDescription.text =  "description"

    return cell
} 


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //let i = IndexPath(item: titles.count, section: 0)
    collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .right, animated: true)
    print("Selected")
    collectionView.reloadData()
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    return 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let frameSize = collectionView.frame.size
    return CGSize(width: frameSize.width, height: frameSize.height)
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let frameSize = collectionView.frame.size
    return CGSize(width: frameSize.width, height: frameSize.height)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {

     return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 5, bottom: 0, right: 5)
}
```

The UICollectionView width and height are 267, 153.
The UICollectioViewCell width and height 262, 150
The Section Insets are 0,0,0,0.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Edit: I added in code I was trying to use for the layout.  I am probably missing something else too.

Comment: Try to give full width and test how it looks

Comment: I've tried that but no luck.

Comment: There is no layout code here.

Comment: I added in additional code I tried.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix using these two functions:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    return 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let frameSize = collectionView.frame.size
    return CGSize(width: frameSize.width, height: frameSize.height)
}
```

Comment: Spent a whole day and here's the answer I was looking for.